# Quotienting a curve by finite automorphism subgroup.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, algebraic-curves, quotient-spaces

Let $Y$ be a smooth projective curve of genus $g$. Let $\Gamma$ be a finite subgroup of the group of automorphisms.

> 1. What does $Y/{\Gamma}$ mean? I know by GIT we can take good quotients of semistable points under a reduction group action. How can we take quotient of the whole of $Y$?

Let $E$ be a vector bundle on $Y$ and we have $h : Y \to Y/{\Gamma}$.

> 2. Is $h_{*}E$ a vector bundle on $Y/{\Gamma}$?

Comment: Could $Y/\Gamma$ just be the smooth projective curve with function field $K(Y)^{\Gamma}$? This seems to be the easiest object to construct.

Comment: That seems like the best explanation. But can you elaborate why given a field we can produce a smooth curve with that as its function field?

Comment: Also, this answers my other question. The pushforward is going to be a torsion free coherent sheaf and hence locally free (since $Y/{\Gamma}$ is a smooth curve)

Comment: First, show that $Y$ can be covered by open affines stable under $\Gamma$. Let $A$ be the ring of regular functions of any of these open affine. Then $A^{\Gamma}$ is still of finite type (see e.g., the chapter 7 of Cox-Little-O'Shea). Now gluing these $\operatorname{Spec}A^{\Gamma}$ gives the quotient curve.

Comment: @Angry_Math_Person: it (curve with given function field on a base field) should be in every text about curves. For a finitely generated function field $K$ of transcendance degree $1$ over a base field $k$, consider $X$ the space of $\mathbb{Z}$-valuations of $K$ trivial over $k$.